# printf a literal number (int) while expecting a shorter number

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, variadic-functions

Let's say we have this line of code:

```
printf("%hi", 6);
```

Let's assume `sizeof(short) == 2`, and `sizeof(int) == 4`.

`printf` expects a `short`, but is given an `int`, which is wider.  Is this undefined behaviour?

The same with `%hhi`.

Comment: Doesn't `6` fit in a `short`?

Comment: @P.W It does, but I don't know exactly how parameters of printf work. I only know they work in a really weird way.  I think it's not as easy as "it gets casted to the type it needs".

Comment: Read about [default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions)

Comment: @P.W. Why are you quoting `c++` links for `c` question?

Comment: @Vagish My link is for C.

Comment: @Barmar Example on that link is a bit funny though, because all parameters are already `int` so promotions have no effect.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito As I understand it, cppreference.com is both C and C++, and all the pages are labeled accordingly.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: If you are comfortable reading the standard. Then see: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf. Section 7.21.6.1

Comment: The answer to this depends on how literally you want to take the wording of the standard (aka. how pedantic one feels). The printf specification has several problems that demand a common-sense approach rather than a literal reading

Comment: @M.M As literal as any compiler writer (mostly I use GCC) will take it, so that any optimizations/implementations they ever do, don't ever break my code :) (Usual flags are `-std=c17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`, no pedantic mode)

Comment: I eagerly await the day that `printf("%u", 1);` formats the hard drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf()` doesn't actually expect the argument to be a `short` when you use `%hi`. When you call a variadic function, all the arguments undergo [default argument promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions). In the case of integer arguments, this means integer promotions, which means that all integer types smaller than `int` are converted to `int` or `unsigned int`.

If the corresponding argument is a literal, all that's required is that it be a value that will fit into a `short`, you don't actually have to cast it to `short`.

The [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.21.6.1.7 explains it this way:

> the argument will
>   have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall
>   be converted to `short int` or `unsigned short int` before printing

Comment: In the standard this is explained (at least) in 7.21.6.1.7

Comment: Thanks, I added the relevant line from that section.